# Function is not returning the value (in most cases)

Tags: python, function, return

I created this function to return the **closest prime to x** (equal or above):

```
def primo(x):
i=2
prime=True
if x>=0:
    while i<=x**(1/2) and prime==True:
        if x%i==0:
            prime=False
        else:
            i+=1
    if (prime==True or x==2 or x==3) and x>1:
        return x
    else:
        primo(x+1)

else:
    primo(x+1)
```

But it only returns when `x` is already prime.

I have tried to put a `print(x)` on the same line as the return, but if `x` is not prime (12, for example), it only prints the number at the end, it does not return the value.

I would like the code to return the prime in every case, most especially if `x` is not prime (it would go around the code until `x` is prime).

Thanks.

Comment: im pretty sure there are built in methods to python to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You need to `return` the value of your recursive function call

```
else:
    return primo(x+1)
```